# Android animate Layout movement

Tags: android, animation, layout

I will try to describe what I want the more precisely I can. I am pretty sure it can be done with a simple animation but I can't really find the words to describe the behavior I am waiting for.

I am currently displaying a `LinearLayout` containing two other `LinearLayout` *childs*. The parent's gravity is set to `center`.

I am able to switch the first child visibility from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` and vice-versa, when clicking on a button.

If the first child `layout` is set to `GONE` and I change it to `VISIBLE`, it will appear on the screen and the `second` child will move to the bottom to give some space. (as the gravity is set to center).

That's what I'd like to animate, when the second child moves to the top/bottom, to let the first one appear / disappear, so it's not instantaneous but smooth.

Here is an animated GIF that shows the whole thing :

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that a animation can be applied to my layouts, in order to animate their moves :

```
    LayoutTransition rpTransition = layout.getLayoutTransition();
    rpTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this :

```
//in onCreate
fadingView.setAlpha(0);

...

public void fadeThenSlide (final View fadingView, final View slidingView ){
   slidingView.animate().translationYBy(fadingView.getHeight()).
   setDuration(200).
   setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            fadingView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(200);
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't tested the code yet so there might be some problems, you can try it and tell me

Comment: The thing is that when setting the FadingView to VISIBLE, it automatically moves the slidingView. So when the fading animation ends, it moves the sliding view that already moved...

Comment: Maybe I could try replacing the LinearLayout by RelativeLayout so only your animation will move the view

Comment: No, you don't need to replace anything, just remove the part of your code where you change the visibility of your fadingView to `gone`.

Comment: Hmm, the thing is that my view is initially set to gone. I think your code would work with invisible and relative layouts

Comment: Oooh, I get it now, I just watched your gif the other way

Comment: I edited my code, but you need to remove all your `visibility` attributes in xml, and overlap your two views. What will happen is that you will set the alpha of the first view to 0, which will make the view invisible, then when you call the animation, the second view will slide down and the invisible view will be visible .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110715/discussion-between-maltesefalcon-and-david-seroussi).